# get all row ids which have value within a certain range of given column in pyspark

Tags: python, apache-spark, pyspark, group-by, user-defined-functions

I have a pyspark dataframe with two cols: [id, val]. I want to create a dataframe result_df which will have an extra column that contains list of all the ids from the same df where difference in val is +/- some threshold.

For example: if the threshold is 2.
which means we need ids having values in range [val-2,val+2]

Whats the most optimal way to achieve it in pyspark?

Comment: [Why should I not upload images of code/data/errors?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-should-i-not-upload-images-of-code-data-errors)

Comment: It's best practice to define the sample dataframe in the question so folks don't have to transcribe the data in your picture to create in their local environment to solve the question. Help us help you. That being said, with tools like github co-pilot, mocking up sample data for a dataframe can be done pretty quickly anymore.

Answer (score 1):

Because the self-join criteria of this merge is rather complex, it may be easiest to solve in SQL where this logic is pretty easy to write:

```
#define dataframe:
df = spark.createDataFrame([{'id':'a', 'val':1},{'id':'b', 'val':2},{'id':'c', 'val':3},{'id':'d', 'val':4}])

#create temp view for sql
df.createOrReplaceTempView("df")

#using array_join (similar to LISTAGG or STRING_AGG in other RDBMS's)
#Doing a self join; joining on +/- val
qry = '''
    SELECT df1. id, df1.val, array_join(collect_list(df2.id), ',')
    FROM df as df1 
       LEFT OUTER JOIN df as df2 
         ON df1.val BETWEEN df2.val - 2 and df2.val + 2
            AND df1.val <> df2.val
    GROUP BY df1.id, df1.val
    '''


spark.sql(qry).show()
```

---

```
+---+---+-------------------------------+
| id|val|array_join(collect_list(id), ,)|
+---+---+-------------------------------+
|  a|  1|                            b,c|
|  d|  4|                            b,c|
|  c|  3|                          a,b,d|
|  b|  2|                          a,c,d|
+---+---+-------------------------------+
```

Answer (score 1):

you could also use a Range window.

here's an example

```py
threshold = 2

data_sdf. \
    withColumn('val_ls1', 
               func.collect_list('id').
               over(wd.partitionBy(func.lit(1)).orderBy('val').rangeBetween(-threshold, -1))
               ). \
    withColumn('val_ls2', 
               func.collect_list('id').
               over(wd.partitionBy(func.lit(1)).orderBy('val').rangeBetween(1, threshold))
               ). \
    withColumn('val_ls', func.array_union('val_ls1', 'val_ls2')). \
    show(truncate=False)

# +---+---+-------+-------+---------+
# |id |val|val_ls1|val_ls2|val_ls   |
# +---+---+-------+-------+---------+
# |a  |1  |[]     |[b, c] |[b, c]   |
# |b  |2  |[a]    |[c, d] |[a, c, d]|
# |c  |3  |[a, b] |[d]    |[a, b, d]|
# |d  |4  |[b, c] |[]     |[b, c]   |
# +---+---+-------+-------+---------+
```